# Nativescript ActionBar custom component

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to create a custom component as described [here](https://moduscreate.com/custom-components-in-nativescript/) in order to reuse the action bar and its logic in different places of my app.
Here is what I have setup the component:

> /components/header/header.xml

```
<ActionBar title="Title" class="{{ 'mode' == dark ? 'bg-dark' : 'bg-white' }}" loaded="loaded">
</ActionBar>
```

> /components/header/header.ts

```
exports.loaded = (args) => {
    let page = <Page> args.object;
    let pageObservable = new Observable({
        'mode' : page.get('mode')
    });
    page.bindingContext = pageObservable;
}
```

I then try to use the component calling it like this :

> some_view.xml

```
<Page 
 xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
 xmlns:header="components/header">

<header:header mode="dark"/>
<StackLayout>..</StackLayout>
...
</Page>
```

However, navigating to `some-view.xml' I get the following error:

```
Calling js method onCreateView failed
TypeError: Cannot read property frame of 'undefined'
File "data...../ui/action-bar/action-bar.js" line: 146
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Have you succeded in creating a custom component based on ActionBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that you are trying to get Page instance in the `loaded` method in your `/components/header/header.ts` file. `args` will return you reference to the `ActionBar` instead of `Page`. On other hand while using TypeScript the events should be defined like this `export function loaded(args){...}`. In the above-given code you are using JavaScript syntax.  I am attaching sample code, where has been shown, how to create custom component.

**component/action-bar/action-bar.xml**

```
<ActionBar loaded="actionbarLoaded" title="Title" icon="">
    <NavigationButton text="Back" icon="" tap="" />
    <ActionBar.actionItems>
        <ActionItem icon="" text="Left" tap="" ios.position="left" />
        <ActionItem icon="" text="Right" tap="" ios.position="right" />
    </ActionBar.actionItems>
</ActionBar>
```

**component/action-bar/action-bar.ts**

```
export function actionbarLoaded(args){
     console.log("actionbar loaded");
 }
```

**main-page.xml**

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo" xmlns:AB="component/action-bar">
<Page.actionBar>
     <AB:action-bar />
</Page.actionBar>
  <StackLayout>
    <Label text="Tap the button" class="title"/>
    <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ onTap }}" />
    <Label text="{{ message }}" class="message" textWrap="true"/>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

**main-page.ts**

```
import { EventData } from 'data/observable';
import { Page } from 'ui/page';
import { HelloWorldModel } from './main-view-model';

// Event handler for Page "navigatingTo" event attached in main-page.xml
export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
  // Get the event sender
  let page = <Page>args.object;
  page.bindingContext = new HelloWorldModel();
}
```